# Stream image file to HttpResponse efficiently

Tags: dart, dart-io, dart-async

My server-side Dart web app serves image files for certain requests.

Simplified, here's what it currently does:

```dart
   HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 80)
    .then((HttpServer server) {    
      server.listen((HttpRequest request) {      
        request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.OK;
        request.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.parse("image/jpg");
        var file = new File("C:\\images\\myImage.jpg");
        file.readAsBytes().then((List<int> bytes) {
          bytes.forEach((int b) => request.response.writeCharCode(b)); // slow!
          request.response.close();       
        });    
      }
   }
```

This works, but it's fairly slow and I suspect that writing every byte individually via `HttpResponse.writeCharCode` is what's slowing things down here.

Unfortunately, there's no such thing as `.writeAllCharCodes` on [HttpResponse](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart%3aio.HttpResponse). There's [writeAll](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.HttpResponse#id_writeAll), but it calls `toString()` on every element of the byte array - we need to write the raw bytes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might help you - I got a speed up of about 4-5 times:

I will add my complete example here:

```dart
Future<ServerSocket> future = ServerSocket.bind("127.0.0.1", 1000);
future.then((ServerSocket sock) {
  HttpServer s = new HttpServer.listenOn(sock);

  s.listen((HttpRequest req) {
    req.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.OK;
    req.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.parse("image/png");
    var file = new File("someImage.png");

    // Average of about 5-7ms
    Future f = file.readAsBytes();
    req.response.addStream(f.asStream()).whenComplete(() {
      req.response.close();
    });
    // Average of ~25-30ms
    /*
    file.readAsBytes().then((List<int> bytes) {
      bytes.forEach((int b) => req.response.writeCharCode(b)); // slow!
      req.response.close();       
    });
    */ 
  });
});
```

Does this resolve your problem?

Regards
Robert

Comment: Just want to mention that res.addStream(stream).whenComplete(res.close) is the same as doing stream.pipe(res).

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account @Anders Johnsen's comment you could do this.

```dart
File f = new File( "image_file.png" )
  ..readAsBytes()
    .asStream()
    .pipe( req.response );
```

Personally I like this one because it makes use of Darts method cascading, but either works.