# How to respond to socket on dart

Tags: sockets, dart

I have simple dart server that works as expected

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  ServerSocket.bind('127.0.0.1', 9999)
  .then((serverSocket) {
    print('connected');
    serverSocket.listen((socket) {
      socket.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((data){
        print(data);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

How to respond to the socket with custom JSON or XML. I get XML also, when I print, it prints as string.

thank you

Comment: What do you mean with `how to respond to the socket with custom JSON or XML`? Do you want to know how to create this JSON/XML or how to send it? In which form do you have the data you want to send currently?

Comment: How to send it, I found an example on how to create it

Comment: Can you please add the code that shows how you create it to your question. Then we know what you are dealing with and can probably point you to an appropriate solution.

Comment: Here you can find an example how you can send binary data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318528. You can use `req.response.addString(...)` or `req.response.write(...)` to send a string. See also http://jamesslocum.com/post/67566023889

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the job if what you want to send is a string.

```dart
socket.response.write(data);
// socket.response.close();
```

See also http://pastebin.com/fgiyCj68 for a complete example